# Thread synchronization issue in Python

Tags: python

I'm having a problem with thread synchronization. I don't understand how to synchronize them correctly. I need to make sure that while the continue_program method is working, all other methods are locked, because even if I write no or anything other than yes, then the start_server () method will still work.

Code:

```py
import socket
import threading


class Server:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.flag = True
        self.locker = threading.Lock()

    def start_server(self):
        self.server.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.server.listen(5)
        print("Created the server")

        while self.flag:
            print("Waiting when client connects")
            client, _ = self.server.accept()
            print("Client connected")
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_client, args=(client,))
            t.start()

    def handle_client(self, client):
        while self.flag:
            data = client.recv(4096)
            data = data.decode("utf-8")
            if data:
                print(f"Data received: \n{data}")
                self.continue_program()

    def continue_program(self):
        con_inp = input("Continue(yes,no)?: ")
        if con_inp.lower() in ["yes", "y"]:
            return
        else:
            self.flag = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj_server = Server("127.0.0.1", 8080)
    obj_server.start_server()
```

Please help to synchronize all these functions.

Comment: There is (edit: there _was_) nothing multithreaded in this program.

Comment: With the edited code, you now can have multiple threads each ending up in `self.continue_program()`, asking for input from the user. What is it you're actually after here?

Comment: my self.flag is not updated in the start_server method, even if I enter no due to the fact that the methods (functions with threads are not synchronized. But I don’t know how to synchronize them correctly in this case.

Comment: You will make your life much easier if you separate the server and client functionality into discrete classes. Also, how do you propose to stop the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I solved the problem. There are already 2 options for solving the problem.
You can use Event from the threading module or Condition, which is also from the threading module.

As far as I understand, this code makes no sense. I just make it synchronous when it needs to run on different threads. But still it was good practice to understand how to synchronize threads.

First solution:

Using Event:

```
import socket
import threading


class Server:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.flag = True
        self.event = threading.Event()

    def start_server(self):
        self.server.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.server.listen(5)
        print("Created the server")

        while self.flag:
            print("Waiting when client connects")
            client, _ = self.server.accept()
            print("Client connected")
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_client, args=(client,))
            t.start()

            # synchronization
            self.event.wait()
            # when there is an event, the list of expected events is cleared
            self.event.clear()

    def handle_client(self, client):
        while self.flag:
            data = client.recv(4096)
            data = data.decode("utf-8")
            if data:
                print(f"Data received: \n{data}")
                self.continue_program()
            else:
                break

    def continue_program(self):
        con_inp = input("Continue(yes,no)?: ")
        if con_inp.lower() in ["yes", "y"]:
            ...
        else:
            self.flag = False

        self.event.set()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj_server = Server("127.0.0.1", 8080)
    obj_server.start_server()
```

Second solution:

Using Condition:

```
import socket
import threading


class Server:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.flag = True
        self.condition = threading.Condition()

    def start_server(self):
        self.server.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.server.listen(5)
        print("Created the server")

        while self.flag:
            print("Waiting when client connects")
            client, _ = self.server.accept()
            print("Client connected")
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_client, args=(client,))
            t.start()

            # synchronization
            with self.condition:
                self.condition.wait()

    def handle_client(self, client):
        while self.flag:
            data = client.recv(4096)
            data = data.decode("utf-8")
            if data:
                print(f"Data received: \n{data}")
                self.continue_program()
            else:
                break

    def continue_program(self):
        con_inp = input("Continue(yes,no)?: ")
        if con_inp.lower() in ["yes", "y"]:
            ...
        else:
            self.flag = False

        # Unlocking start_server loop
        with self.condition:
            self.condition.notify_all()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj_server = Server("127.0.0.1", 8080)
    obj_server.start_server()
```